# React Native: Show bottomTabNavigator on all pages

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get the `bottomTabNavigator` to show on all screens. This is how I have mine set up, I don't quite understand how react navigation works just yet but based on what I've read it seems like the `bottomTabNavigator` should be the top level component with stack navigators added to it, I'm just not sure how to do that.

**AppNavigator.js**

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
    Landing: LandingScreen,
    Menu: MenuNavigator

  })
);
```

**MainTabNavigator.js**

```
...

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  CalendarStack,
  BoardStack,
  MomentsStack
});

tabNavigator.path = '';


export default tabNavigator;
```

**MenuNavigator.js**

```
const MenuNavigator= createStackNavigator({
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Contact: {screen: ContactScreen},
    Faq: {screen: FaqScreen},
    Help: {screen: HelpScreen}

  });

export default MenuNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add path in createBottomTabNavigator by using createStackNavigator . 
for Example I have to move to settings and contact from Home navigation

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:createStackNavigator({
      HomeStack,
      SettingsScreen,
      ContactScreen,
    }),
  CalendarStack,
  BoardStack,
  MomentsStack
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have bottomtabs in all screen in your app you should create like this

```js
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  CalendarStack,
  BoardStack,
  MomentsStack
});
and
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: tabNavigator ,
   ,
   

  })
);
```

Comment: oh my god I can believe that

Answer (score 0):

> Note - Tab navigator will be available only on those screens which are
>   defined under tabNavigator stack. So you would have to maintain your
>   stack in a way that the screens in which you want to show the tab
>   navigator must be in the tab navigator stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your main tab screen,include this navigationoption,`navigationOptions:{tabBarVisible:true}`

`const Tabs=createBottomTabNavigator({
  myorder:{screen:MyOrderScreens,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLable:'Myorder',
      tabBarVisible:true,
      tabBarIcon:({navigation})=>(
       <Image source={require('./images/orders_1.png')} style={{width:30,height:30}}/>
       )
    }
  },`